# how can I make restrictions if I want to delete a data in the database and it is foreign key in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have two tables named `"location"` which consist of `"location_id"` and `"location_name"` and the other table is `"computer"` which have the `"location"` as a foreign key. Now whenever I want to delete a data which is used in the table `"computer"` I got an error message:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1451
>
> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`cmms`.`computer`, CONSTRAINT `computer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`location`) REFERENCES `location` (`location_id`))
>
> DELETE FROM `location` WHERE `location_id` = '30'
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/cmms/application/models/asset_model.php
>
> Line Number: 9

How can I check if it exist in table "computer" there will be a message and if it doesn't exist it will automatically delete the data in "location" table?

my code in my controller which is `asset_management.php` is:

```
public function deleteloc(){
  $this->load->model("asset_model");
  $u = $this->uri->segment(3);
  $this->asset_model->deletelocation($u);
  redirect('asset_management/locations');         
}
```

My code in my model which is asset_model is:

```
public function deletelocation($a){
    $this->db->delete('location', array('location_id' => $a));
    return;
}
```

please help. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove a value from the computer table before being able to remove this row. There is a row in the computer table depending on this row.